# Show $-\frac{1}{4}(5^{k+1}-1) = -\frac{1}{4}(5^k-1)-5^k$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm just trying to simplify an expression for a question, the question itself is irrelevant but the answer I need for the question is below. The stage where I don't know how to achieve the answer is also written below.

My answer should be:

$-\frac{1}{4}(5^{k+1}-1)$

and I have:

$-\frac{1}{4}(5^k-1)-5^k$

I understand that I need to expand it but I'm confused on the simplication from there. If I could have a step-by-step solution for how the answer was reached, that would be great. I've tried using online calculators but I don't understand how it is achieved.

Thank you.

Comment: $$\begin{align*}
-\frac{1}{4}(5^k-1) - 5^k &= -\frac{1}{4}(5^k-1) - \frac{1}{4}(4(5^k))\\
&= -\frac{1}{4}\left(5^k-1 + 4(5^k)\right)\\
&= -\frac{1}{4}\left( 5^k(1+4) - 1\right)\\
&= -\frac{1}{4}\left(5^k(5) - 1\right)\\
&= -\frac{1}{4}\left(5^{k+1}-1\right).
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that it is not obvious.

$-\frac 14(5^{k+1} - 1)\\
-\frac 14(5\cdot 5^{k} - 1)\\
-\frac 14((1+4)5^{k} - 1)\\
-\frac 14(5^{k} + 4\cdot5^k - 1)\\
-\frac 14(5^{k} - 1) - 5^k$

Comment: Thank you for your input. Is there any way I spot these tricks in the future when facing these sorts of questions again?

Comment: @msk 710 I think, yes . If you have two *"different"* expressions that should be equivalent, just set them equal to each other like an equation, then simplify and you will immediately be able to observe where the *"difference"* comes from.  So, you will be able to easily understand why they are equivalent .

Comment: @Mskr710: Here, one expression is a (disguised) fraction, and the other is a fraction plus an integer. That suggests trying to put both expressions into a common form, i.e., cnverting the second expression into a fraction.

Answer (score 0):

**For the sake of variety, I offer an alternate proof using the $n$th partial sum of a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)**

$$ \sum_{i=0}^n a^i = \frac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-a} $$

**given below:**

$
\begin{array}{llll}
-\frac{1}{4} ( 5^{k+1} - 1 ) \\
= -\frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{4}{4} \cdot \Big( 5^{k+1} - 1 \Big) \\
= -\frac{1}{4} \cdot 4 \cdot \frac{5^{k+1}-1}{4} \\
= (-1) \frac{5^{k+1}-1}{4} \\
= (-1) \frac{1-5^{k+1}}{-4} \\
= (-1) \frac{1-5^{k+1}}{1-5} \\
= (-1) \sum_{i=0}^k 5^i \\
= (-1) \Big( 5^k + \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} 5^i \Big) \\
= -5^k - \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} 5^i \\
= -\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} 5^i - 5^k \\
= -\frac{1-5^k}{1-5} - 5^k\\
= -\frac{1-5^k}{-4} - 5^k \\
= \frac{5^k-1}{-4} - 5^k \\
= \Big( \frac{5^k}{-4} - \frac{1}{-4}\Big) - 5^k\\
= \Big( \frac{-1}{4} \cdot 5^k + \frac{1}{4}\Big) - 5^k \\
= -\frac{1}{4} (5^k - 1) - 5^k
\end{array}
$